# Count cumulative unique factors separated by semicolon Grouped by Name

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, zoo

This is what my dataframe looks like. The two rightmost columns are my desired columns. I am counting the cumulative number of unique FundTypes as of each row.The 4th columns is the cumulative unique count for all "ActivityType" and the 5th column is the cumulative unique count for only "ActivityType=="Sale".

```
dt <- read.table(text='

Name      ActivityType     FundType  UniqueFunds(AllTypes) UniqueFunds(SaleOnly)         

John       Email               a            1                     0
John       Sale                a;b          2                     2 
John       Webinar             c;d          4                     2
John       Sale                b            4                     2
John       Webinar             e            5                     2
John       Conference          b;d          5                     2
John       Sale                b;e          5                     3
Tom        Email               a            1                     0
Tom        Sale                a;b          2                     2 
Tom        Webinar             c;d          4                     2
Tom        Sale                b            4                     2
Tom        Webinar             e            5                     2
Tom        Conference          b;d          5                     2
Tom        Sale                b;e;f        6                     4                    

                         ', header=T, row.names = NULL)
```

I have tried `dt[, UniqueFunds := cumsum(!duplicated(FundType)& !FundType=="") ,by = Name]` but for example it counts a & a;b & c;d  as 3 unique values as opposed to the desired 4 unique values as the factors are separated by semicolon.Kindly let me know of a solution.

UPDATE: My real dataset looks more like this:

```
dt <- read.table(text='

    Name      ActivityType     FundType  UniqueFunds(AllTypes) UniqueFunds(SaleOnly)         
    John       Email               ""           0                     0
    John       Conference          ""           0                     0
    John       Email               a            1                     0
    John       Sale                a;b          2                     2 
    John       Webinar             c;d          4                     2
    John       Sale                b            4                     2
    John       Webinar             e            5                     2
    John       Conference          b;d          5                     2
    John       Sale                b;e          5                     3
    John       Email               ""           5                     3
    John       Webinar             ""           5                     3
    Tom        Email               a            1                     0
    Tom        Sale                a;b          2                     2 
    Tom        Webinar             c;d          4                     2
    Tom        Sale                b            4                     2
    Tom        Webinar             e            5                     2
    Tom        Conference          b;d          5                     2
    Tom        Sale                b;e;f        6                     4                    

                             ', header=T, row.names = NULL)
```

The unique cumulative vectors need to take into account the missing values.

Comment: `FundCode` is not part of your data frame, can you clarify this.

Comment: It was an error. Thank you for catching it. I fixed it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but for `Name == "John" & ActivityType == "Sale"` there *are* only 3 unique `FundType`s - `a;b` (row 2), `b` (row 4), and `b;e` (row 7), no? Unless you were referring to something else here: *"but it counts a;b and b;c and c;d as 3 unique values"*?

Comment: @nrussell you are right, my example was outside the context of the dataframe I presented. It was more of a general example. I can fix it if you think  what I have in the post is confusing.

Comment: It would probably help to clarify that - or possibly just edit the example data by changing row 4 from `b` to `b;c` for `FundType` and including the code you used to generate the fourth and fifth columns.

Comment: I edited it. 4th and 5th columns are my desired columns. I dont have the code(dont know how) to generate those target columns.  I tried to articulate my logic in the post in regards to how the columns should be derived.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

nrussell suggested a concise solution writing a custom function. Let me drop what I got. I tried to used `cumsum()` and `duplicated()` as you tried. I did two major operations. One for `alltype` and the other for `saleonly`. First, I created indices for each name. Then, I split `FundType` and formatted the data in a long format with `cSplit()` from the splitstackshape package. Then, I chose the last row for each index number for each Name. Finally, I chose only one column, `alltype`.

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(zoo)
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)[, ind := 1:.N, by = "Name"]
cSplit(dt, "FundType", sep = ";", direction = "long")[,
    alltype := cumsum(!duplicated(FundType)), by = "Name"][,
    .SD[.N], by = c("Name", "ind")][, list(alltype)] -> alltype
```

The second operation was for saleonly. Basically, I repeated the same approach to a subsetted data for sale, which is `ana`. I also created a data set without sale, which is `ana2`. Then, I created a list with the two data sets (i.e., `l`) and bound them. I changed the order of the dataset with `Name` and `ind`, take the last rows for each name and index number, taking care of NAs (filling NAs and replacing the first NA for each Name with 0), and finally chose one column. The final operation was to combine the original `dt`, `alltype`, and `saleonly`.

```
# data for sale only
cSplit(dt, "FundType", sep = ";", direction = "long")[
    ActivityType == "Sale"][,
    saleonly := cumsum(!duplicated(FundType)), by = "Name"] -> ana

# Data without sale
cSplit(dt, "FundType", sep = ";", direction = "long")[
    ActivityType != "Sale"] -> ana2 

# Combine ana and ana2
l <- list(ana, ana2)
rbindlist(l, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE) -> temp
setorder(temp, Name, ind)[,
    .SD[.N], by = c("Name", "ind")][,
    saleonly := na.locf(saleonly, na.rm = FALSE), by = "Name"][,
    saleonly := replace(saleonly, is.na(saleonly), 0)][, list(saleonly)] -> saleonly

cbind(dt, alltype, saleonly)

    Name ActivityType FundType UniqueFunds.AllTypes. UniqueFunds.SaleOnly. ind alltype saleonly
 1: John        Email        a                     1                     0   1       1        0
 2: John         Sale      a;b                     2                     2   2       2        2
 3: John      Webinar      c;d                     4                     2   3       4        2
 4: John         Sale        b                     4                     2   4       4        2
 5: John      Webinar        e                     5                     2   5       5        2
 6: John   Conference      b;d                     5                     2   6       5        2
 7: John         Sale      b;e                     5                     3   7       5        3
 8:  Tom        Email        a                     1                     0   1       1        0
 9:  Tom         Sale      a;b                     2                     2   2       2        2
10:  Tom      Webinar      c;d                     4                     2   3       4        2
11:  Tom         Sale        b                     4                     2   4       4        2
12:  Tom      Webinar        e                     5                     2   5       5        2
13:  Tom   Conference      b;d                     5                     2   6       5        2
14:  Tom         Sale    b;e;f                     6                     4   7       6        4
```

**EDIT**

For the new data set, I tried the following. Basically, I used my approach for the saleonly data to this new data set. The revision was only in the `alltype` part. First, I added indices, replaced "" with NA, and subsetted the data with rows having non-NA values. This is `temp`. The rest is identical to the previous answer. Now I wanted to have the data set with NAs in FundType, so I used `setdiff()`. Using `rbindlist()`, I combined the two data sets and created `temp`. The rest is identical to the previous answer. The sale-part does not have any changes. I hope this will work for your real data.

```
### all type

setDT(dt)[, ind := 1:.N, by = "Name"][,
    FundType := replace(FundType, which(FundType == ""), NA)][FundType != ""] -> temp
cSplit(temp, "FundType", sep = ";", direction = "long")[,
    alltype := cumsum(!duplicated(FundType)), by = "Name"] -> alltype


whatever <- list(setdiff(dt, temp), alltype)
rbindlist(whatever, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE) -> temp
setorder(temp, Name, ind)[,.SD[.N], by = c("Name", "ind")][,
    alltype := na.locf(alltype, na.rm = FALSE), by = "Name"][,
    alltype := replace(alltype, is.na(alltype), 0)][, list(alltype)] -> alltype


### sale only
cSplit(dt, "FundType", sep = ";", direction = "long")[
    ActivityType == "Sale"][,
    saleonly := cumsum(!duplicated(FundType)), by = "Name"] -> ana

cSplit(dt, "FundType", sep = ";", direction = "long")[
    ActivityType != "Sale"] -> ana2

l <- list(ana, ana2)
rbindlist(l, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE) -> temp
setorder(temp, Name, ind)[,
    .SD[.N], by = c("Name", "ind")][,
    saleonly := na.locf(saleonly, na.rm = FALSE), by = "Name"][,
    saleonly := replace(saleonly, is.na(saleonly), 0)][, list(saleonly)] -> saleonly

cbind(dt, alltype, saleonly)


    Name ActivityType FundType UniqueFunds.AllTypes. UniqueFunds.SaleOnly. ind alltype saleonly
 1: John        Email       NA                     0                     0   1       0        0
 2: John   Conference       NA                     0                     0   2       0        0
 3: John        Email        a                     1                     0   3       1        0
 4: John         Sale      a;b                     2                     2   4       2        2
 5: John      Webinar      c;d                     4                     2   5       4        2
 6: John         Sale        b                     4                     2   6       4        2
 7: John      Webinar        e                     5                     2   7       5        2
 8: John   Conference      b;d                     5                     2   8       5        2
 9: John         Sale      b;e                     5                     3   9       5        3
10: John        Email       NA                     5                     3  10       5        3
11: John      Webinar       NA                     5                     3  11       5        3
12:  Tom        Email        a                     1                     0   1       1        0
13:  Tom         Sale      a;b                     2                     2   2       2        2
14:  Tom      Webinar      c;d                     4                     2   3       4        2
15:  Tom         Sale        b                     4                     2   4       4        2
16:  Tom      Webinar        e                     5                     2   5       5        2
17:  Tom   Conference      b;d                     5                     2   6       5        2
18:  Tom         Sale    b;e;f                     6                     4   7       6        4
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: @gibbz00 Pleasure to help you. :)

Comment: My original dataframe was 3M+ rows. "alltype" and "saleonly" comes out to be around  1 Million rows. Not sure how the final cbind will work. The FundType column in the original dataframe has a lot of missing values. So for example, the alltype starts with 1122233 etc. rather than 00001122333. How do I modify your solution to take into account all the missing values?

Comment: @gibbz00 Would you be able to create a small example capturing the nature of your real data? Then, SO users can deliver better solutions. If you can add another data set as an edit part, that will be great.

Comment: I just edited it. I hope it better represents the problem.

Comment: @gibbz00 You may want to leave the previous data set as well since all answers are based on that.

Comment: @gibbz00 I did wha I could do for now with the new data set. I hope this will help you with the large data set.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is one way to achieve what you are after. Start by adding an auxiliary index variable for maintaining the input order; and `key`ing on `Name`:

```
Dt <- copy(dt[, 1:3, with = FALSE])[, gIdx := 1:.N, by = "Name"]
setkeyv(Dt, "Name")
```

For clarity, I used this function

```
n_usplit <- function(x, spl = ";") length(unique(unlist(strsplit(x, split = spl))))
```

rather than typing out the body's expression on the fly - the operation below is dense enough as it is without a bunch of nested function calls convoluting things.

And finally,

```
Dt[Dt, allow.cartesian = TRUE][
  gIdx <= i.gIdx, 
  .("UniqueFunds(AllTypes)" = n_usplit(FundType),
    "UniqueFunds(SaleOnly)" = n_usplit(FundType[ActivityType == "Sale"])),
  keyby = "Name,i.gIdx,i.ActivityType,i.FundType"][,-2, with = FALSE]
#      Name i.ActivityType i.FundType UniqueFunds(AllTypes) UniqueFunds(SaleOnly)
# 1:   John          Email          a                     1                     0
# 2:   John           Sale        a;b                     2                     2
# 3:   John        Webinar        c;d                     4                     2
# 4:   John           Sale          b                     4                     2
# 5:   John        Webinar          e                     5                     2
# 6:   John     Conference        b;d                     5                     2
# 7:   John           Sale        b;e                     5                     3
# 8:    Tom          Email          a                     1                     0
# 9:    Tom           Sale        a;b                     2                     2
# 10:   Tom        Webinar        c;d                     4                     2
# 11:   Tom           Sale          b                     4                     2
# 12:   Tom        Webinar          e                     5                     2
# 13:   Tom     Conference        b;d                     5                     2
# 14:   Tom           Sale      b;e;f                     6                     4
```

---

I feel like I could explain this easier with SQL, but here we go:

1. Join `Dt` on itself (by `Name`)
2. Using the extra index column (`gIdx`), only consider previous (inclusive) rows in sequence - this results in a sort of cumulative effect (for lack of better term)
3. Calculate the `UniqueFunds(...)` columns - notice the extra subsetting done in the second case - `n_usplit(FundType[ActivityType == "Sale"])`
4. Drop the extraneous index column (`i.gIdx`).

---

I'm not sure how this will scale due to the use of a cartesian join, so hopefully your real data set isn't millions of rows.

---

**Data:**

```
library(data.table)
##
dt <- fread('
Name      ActivityType     FundType  UniqueFunds(AllTypes) UniqueFunds(SaleOnly)         
John       Email               a            1                     0
John       Sale                a;b          2                     2 
John       Webinar             c;d          4                     2
John       Sale                b            4                     2
John       Webinar             e            5                     2
John       Conference          b;d          5                     2
John       Sale                b;e          5                     3
Tom        Email               a            1                     0
Tom        Sale                a;b          2                     2 
Tom        Webinar             c;d          4                     2
Tom        Sale                b            4                     2
Tom        Webinar             e            5                     2
Tom        Conference          b;d          5                     2
Tom        Sale                b;e;f        6                     4                     
            ', header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: I have to turn the "FundType" column from factor to character, right? This is what I had to do for the final code to work.

Comment: @gibbz00 Yes, sorry I assumed they were not factors (I have this feature turned off by default in my sessions).

Comment: Why are we keying by ["Name,i.gIdx,i.ActivityType,i.FundType"] in the final line of the code? Thanks.

Comment: So that those columns are preserved in addition to the two calculated fields.

Comment: Your solution is awesome. Unfortunately my dataframe has 3M+ rows and I am getting cannot allocate vector of size 2.4 Gb despite having 32GB of memory. Kindly let me know if you can think of a workaround

Answer (score 2):

I achieved what you're looking for as follows:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
dt <- data.table(read.table(text='

                 Name      ActivityType     FundType  UniqueFunds(AllTypes) UniqueFunds(SaleOnly)         
                 John       Email               a            1                     0
                 John       Sale                a;b          2                     2 
                 John       Webinar             c;d          4                     2
                 John       Sale                b            4                     2
                 John       Webinar             e            5                     2
                 John       Conference          b;d          5                     2
                 John       Sale                b;e          5                     3
                 Tom        Email               a            1                     0
                 Tom        Sale                a;b          2                     2 
                 Tom        Webinar             c;d          4                     2
                 Tom        Sale                b            4                     2
                 Tom        Webinar             e            5                     2
                 Tom        Conference          b;d          5                     2
                 Tom        Sale                b;e;f        6                     4                    

                 ', header=T, row.names = NULL))

dt[,UniqueFunds.AllTypes. := NULL][,UniqueFunds.SaleOnly. := NULL]

#Get the different Fund Types
vals <- unique(unlist(str_extract_all(dt$FundType,"[a-z]")))

#Construct a new set of columns indicating which fund types are present
dt[,vals:=data.table(1*t(sapply(FundType,str_detect,vals))),with=FALSE]

#Calculate UniqueFunds.AllTypes
dt[, UniqueFunds.AllTypes. := 
     rowSums(sapply(.SD, cummax)), .SDcols = vals, by = Name]

#Calculate only when ActicityType == "Sale" and use cummax to achieve desired output
dt[,UniqueFunds.SaleOnly. := 0
   ][ActivityType == "Sale", UniqueFunds.SaleOnly. := 
     rowSums(sapply(.SD, cummax)), .SDcols = vals, by = Name
   ][,UniqueFunds.SaleOnly. := cummax(UniqueFunds.SaleOnly.), by = Name
     ]

#Cleanup vals
dt[,vals := NULL, with = FALSE]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!